# How to use one button to change an gif image 3 times and then another button to reverse/change the same images backwards

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an application that I'm working on in my career as a beginner, I don't know much and if anyone could help that'll be great. Basically, I have a GifImageView, whenever a user clicks a button that's attached to it, I want the gif to change into another GifImageView and then again, if the user presses the same button, I want the already changed image to change to another GifImageView again. I've managed do to that, now, I want to make an another button. That button should only work if the previous button is clicked three times and the image is already changed three times. When users click on that new button, I want that third image to change to the previous image and when the user clicks again, I want it to change to the first image. So basically, it should be a reverse kind of way of changing the images. Here's what my code looks like so far :

```
addspeed1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GifImageView gifImageView = findViewById(R.id.greengif3);
            if (count == 0) {
                gifImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            } else if (count == 1) {
                gifImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
            }
            count++;

        }
    });

    minusspeed1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GifImageView gifImageView = findViewById(R.id.greengif3);
            if (count == 0) {
                gifImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
            } else if (count == 1) {
                gifImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
            }
            count++;
        }
    });
```

I know the second buttons code is wrong, just adding it for more context. Thanks in advance. Here's some pictures as well : [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to keep it simple since you are a beginner.

I would first make a function that can resolve a drawable resource by speed:

```
private int getDrawableResourceBySpeed(int speed) {
    if (speed == 1) {
        return R.drawable.green;
    } else if (speed == 2) {
        return R.drawable.yellow;
    } else if (speed == 3) {
        return R.drawable.orange;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid speed: " + speed);
    }
}
```

Then 2 functions to increase or decrease speed

```
private void increaseSpeed() {
    if (speed < 3) {
        speed++;
    }
}

private void decreaseSpeed() {
    if (speed > 0) {
        speed--;
    }
}
```

Then call those functions and update the gif

```
addspeed1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            increaseSpeed();
            gifImageView.setImageResource(getDrawableResourceBySpeed(speed));
        }
    });

    minusspeed1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            decreaseSpeed();
            gifImageView.setImageResource(getDrawableResourceBySpeed(speed));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not sure this is exactly what you meant (since you were rambling a bit) but I think it will probably help you figure out the rest.